# Set-OrganizationConfing not recognised, even though I can Get-OrganizationConfig

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying to set the 'Focused Inbox' to disabled for the whole organisation. I've found lots of scripts and tutorials online, most of which point toward using the Exchange Online Session in PowerShell.

e.g.:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/setup/configure-focused-inbox?view=o365-worldwide
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

My PS script is as follows:

```
# Set up Credential
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

# Create the Exchange Online session
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

# Import the cmdlets into this session
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

# Get a list of the organisation's current settings
Get-OrganizationConfig

# Now set the 'Focused Inbox' option to 'off' for everyone
Set-OrganizationConfig -FocusedInboxOn $false

# Must remove the session to avoid clogging and clutter
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

The 'Get-OrganizationConfig' command returns a full list of the current config:

[image]

However, when I execute the 'Set-OrganizationConfig' command, it fails with the following message:

```
Set-OrganizationConfig : The term 'Set-OrganizationConfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
```

path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image]

My presumption is that it's a permissions issue, however, I can *see* all the organisation's config, and it's the cmdlet that's missing.

**What is the problem?**

I am:

- Running PS as 'Adminstrator'
- Using the 'SharePointAdmin' administrator account for the credentials

Comment: I notice that the `Set-OrganizationConfig` error screenshot is of you manually executing the command. Your script loads the session where the Exchange cmdlets are loaded, and then removes that session at the end, which would also take the cmdlets with it. Do you get that same error when the cmdlet in question is run within the script you wrote?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Sorry, that was for illustrative purposes only. Exact same results if run within the script. Besides, I hadn't closed the session when I ran that snippet.

Answer (score 1):

## This was a permissions issue.

Create the `$Session` using an account that has **Global Admin** privileges in your O365 Tenant and you'll see that the `'Set-...'` cmdlets automatically get downloaded and inserted into your session.